# Web Rest API and SSIS - where to start

Tags: api, rest, ssis, walmart-api, cozyroc

We are creating a series of SSIS packages to interact with the Walmart Marketplace APIs and trying to use CozyRoc rest components.  They do not have all of the APIs stubbed out and our team has little knowledge around OpenAPI or how to configure this.

Has anyone worked within this space who can provide some kind of head start or suggest resources we might follow?

Many Thanks,

Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated